# Realm configuration in tomcat for forms authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, forms-authentication

I'm developing a java web project using tomcat. I've successfully implemented forms authentication in my project. 
Is there a way to configure the Realm not in the server.xml?

I need to send my project to someone - and there is a demand that he wouldn't have to do such "extra" configuration.

Is there a way to put the Realm section somewhere in my project - like at web.xml?
Perhaps there is some other way that I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put realm into `server.xml` but also into `context.xml`.

Moreover this is recommended configuration.

Please refer to the following document for details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Comment: But that's does not solves the problem - because context.xml resides at the tomcat server. I need somewhere in/from my project